# Apt-get update not working in Ubuntu 16.04 "temporary failure resolving"

Tags: apt

First of all I am new to Linux command line. I never worked with it before. My problem is that the command `apt-get update` will just return:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My `sources.list` file looks like this:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

My ubuntu version is:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-66-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Do you always face with this problem or it just happened once? It can be because of connection problem. Try it again after few minutes. It should connect.

Comment: Are you running `sudo`?  As in `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: `Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'` That's the root cause of your problem. Can you access http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ in your browser? Can you access other Web sites?

Comment: i've had this happen when my internet service went down or when the wifi connection dropped.  after things were working, again, so too `apt-get update` worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue. The heart of the problem was an inability to resolve DNS. I was missing my `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

The contents of it should be:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Afterwards, restart the correct interface (mine was `lo` instead of `eth0`).  You can find it in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: i prefer *not* to show google what sites i browse and use other DNS servers.  since i have ipv6 my list uses it: 2001:67c:28a4:: and 2001:470:20::2

Comment: you don't need to restart the interface after changing `/etc/resolv.conf`.  you do need to restart continuously running programs that use the resolver, such as firefox.

Comment: How to restart the interface? I notice that every time I add things to /etc/resolv.conf, after restarting returns to origina values.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, caused by incorrect DNS settings:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

In this file set a correct DNS server: `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8`

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but a slightly different error message. This worked for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Find the line for `dns-nameserver`. If you don't have it, add it like this:

```
dns-nameserver 208.067.222.222
```

That is the address for OpenDNS. You can also use 8.8.8.8, which is address for Google Public DNS.