# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 cannot Update/Download/Install

Tags: networking, apt, permissions, updates, apache2

When I run `sudo apt-get update` this is my output:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease  
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'  
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'  
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease  
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'  
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease  
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'  
Reading package lists... Done  
W: Failed to fetch   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease    Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'  
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease    Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'  
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease    Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'  
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease    Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm new to servers and have run into this issue. I've managed to get SSH up and running and am attempting to install Apache. Nothing will install. I am new to Linux servers. I have only worked with Windows Servers before.

Let me know if any other info would be helpful.

Comment: You need root privileges to run apt-get. Try with `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Thanks—I ran that command and posted the updated output in the question.

Comment: This looks really different now. You may take a look for similar questions like https://askubuntu.com/questions/769227/ubuntu-16-04-server-updates-temporary-failure-resolving-ro-archive-ubuntu-com or https://askubuntu.com/questions/892569/apt-get-update-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Do you have routing/DNS problems by chance? What do you get when you run `ping` and `traceroute` for those domains?